# Rearranging Div Structure

Tags: html, css

I have following div structure.

[image]

I want to rearrange this with the **help of C.S.S. only** such that there will be **no space** b/w Div-1(Data: Test-1, 25) & Div-3(Data: Test3, 45).

Here is the [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/jhUcN/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
    Test 1
    <br/>
    25
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div class="abc">
       Test 2
       <br/>
       35
     </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    Test 3
    <br/>
    45
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test{
    width: 48%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;

}
.abc{

    height:75px; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of div 2 height, your 3rd div position gets affected. So you can arrange div 1,3 in a separate div and div 2,4 in separate div like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jhUcN/6/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="test">Test 1
        <br/>25</div>
    <div class="test">Test 3
        <br/>45</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.test {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must make an additional CSS styling property for the right-hand div containers. They're all using the left float attribute, which is not going to work properly.

Try this to CSS:

```
.test-right {
   float: right;
}
```

and to HTML:

```
<div class="test test-right">
    <div class="abc">
    Test 2
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhUcN/12/)

Comment: Thanks. Working properly. Please modified your fiddle, you posted the same.

Comment: Ah, fixed that, forgot to press update before sharing the link!

Answer (score 0):

### Unfortunately...

You cant (sorry).

If the heights of the `div` elements are not known and they must appear left to right, this cannot be accomplished using CSS- you will need to look into using a library like [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

If the heights of the `divs` are known and proportionate- there are a number of solutions (CSS table derivation, or lists), if the display order is top to bottom and not left to right you could also look into using columns.